# PHP MSSQ Nested while loops throw an error

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, pdo, scope

I have two nested while loops, inside, i plan to have a query inside each, but when i nested 2 whiles, on second query php returns "There was a problem connecting to SQL SERVER. SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable no more data may be retrieved "

I'm running Php 7.0 on windows server with mssql2014

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$debug = false;

$serverName = "###"; //serverName\instanceName
$database = '###';
$user = '###';
$pass = '###';

$pagesize = 10; 
$offset = 0;

if($debug) {
    var_dump($response);  
} else {
    try {
        $pdo = new \PDO(
            sprintf(
                "sqlsrv:server=%s;Database=%s",
                $serverName,
                $database
            ),
            //$user, $pass  // depends on how we use the script
             NULL, NULL
        );
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        //query for a set of documents
        $dataset = 'SELECT itemdata.itemnum, itemdata.itemname, 
                    doctype.itemtypename, 
                    useraccount.username,
                    itemdatapage.filepath, itemdatapage.filesize,
                    itemdata.itemdate, itemdata.datestored, itemdata.itemtypenum as itemtypenum 
                    FROM hsi.itemdata as itemdata
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.useraccount ON itemdata.usernum = useraccount.usernum
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.itemdatapage ON itemdata.itemnum = itemdatapage.itemnum 
                    LEFT JOIN hsi.doctype ON itemdata.itemtypenum = doctype.itemtypenum
                    WHERE itemdatapage.itempagenum = 0
                    ORDER BY itemnum
                    OFFSET 90000 ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;';

        $stmt = $pdo->query( $dataset );

        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
            //search keywords table
            $selectTables = 'SELECT keytypenum
                            FROM [OnBase].[hsi].[itemtypexkeyword]
                            WHERE itemtypenum =' . $row['itemtypenum'];

                            $stmt = $pdo->query( $selectTables );

                            while ( $tables = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                             print_r($tables);
                            }

        }




    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "There was a problem connecting to SQL SERVER. " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}
```

Actually i get the error described above running this code of php from console. I spect get all the results from mssql

Answer (score 1):

This line is likely to be the problem:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query( $selectTables );
```

The problem is you've already used `$stmt` to represent your original statement ($stmt = `$pdo->query( $dataset );`). And due to that fact that the second assignment of `$stmt` comes within a loop where you're still trying to loop over the original statement, this causes a logic error. Destroying a variable while you're still using it is pretty much guaranteed to cause problems.

It'll be alright the first time the loop runs, but as soon as the loop tries to run a second time, `$stmt` no longer represents what it originally did, and thus a logical problem arises.

Just change your inner code to use another variable name, e.g.:

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->query( $selectTables );

while ( $tables = $stmt2->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
  print_r($tables);
}
```

and this will create a new statement object, and preserve the original one which is still in use. That should resolve your issue, I expect.

---

P.S. As a general coding rule, re-using the same variable name twice to represent different objects during a block is not considered a good idea. A good quality code review would probably flag it up. It makes understanding (and thus debugging, maintaining and enhancing) the code harder, and can also lead to this kind of accidental logic error. This is especially true of languages like PHP which have rather loose typing and scoping rules.